# Show a list as Gantt chart on Sharepoint page

Tags: sharepoint, gantt-chart

I try to publish a list as Gantt chart on a Sharepoint site. I have been able to create a Gantt view of the list. It has a URL like so:

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/Test2/Lists/Project%20plan/Gantt.aspx

[image: Look att this]

When I go directly to the URL is shows the list a a Gantt as expected. However, when I add the list to a site it shows a standard list (table), the Gantt chart (graphics) is not shown.

[image: Look at this, too]

Why is that? Should I use some other web part? If so, which?

Answer (score 1):

Per my experience, Gantt Views are still not supported in SharePoint Modern experience.

In classic experience, when you go to another view modern experience then it redirects/refreshes page with different URL.

In Modern experience when you change the view it does not redirect to another page. It only appends the view ID in URL and renders the new view in same place without redirecting it to another page.

So if you want to continue using gantt view, you can switch the view to classic experience.